# Draw separate barchart for subcategories using google visualization

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to draw a bar chart using google visualization. I have 11 categories, out of those eleven categories 4 of them have subcategories. The Subcategories are different for different categories. For example:

- a)   Video
- i.   Subcategories: Netflix, YouTube, Vimeo, Vine,
     DailyMotion
- b)   Email & Messaging
- i.   Subcategories: gmail, hotmail,
         yahoomail
- . . .

My requirement is, when onclick of one category on bar chart, the subcategories will display as another bar chart.
Can this be possible using google visualization? Please let me know.

Or is there any other way i can handel this?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible using google visualization, google charts have a select event listener. You want to replace the graph with your sub-categories or just show another one below/besides?

Comment: Thanks Juvian for your response. I want to show another one besides. if you have examples, can you pls post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really simple example of what you can do:

```js
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Category', 'Value'],
          ['Videos',  1000],
          ['Mail',  1170]
        ]);

        
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
              var selection=chart.getSelection();
              if(selection.length == 1){
                  var row = selection[0].row;
                  var col = selection[0].column;
                  var cat = data.getValue(row,0);
                  drawSubChart(cat);
              }
          })
          chart.draw(data, {});
      }

function drawSubChart(cat){
    var arr = [['SubCategory', 'Value']];
    if(cat == 'Videos'){
        arr.push(['Youtube', 700], ['DailyMotion', 300]);
    }else if(cat == 'Mail'){
        arr.push(['Gmail', 600], ['Hotmail', 570]);
    }
    
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));   
    chart.draw(data, {});
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div id="chart_div2" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Juvian, this is exactly what I wanted. You really rock!!

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask further inquires